# Ruby on Rails - Activerecord::Associations method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this basic association setup on both `User` and `Recipe` models as in `User has many recipes` and on view I'm referencing one of recipe attribute like this

```
<%= @recipe.title %>
```

And the error is

```
undefined method `title' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Recipe:0x00000101edeac0>
```

I did some research and it seems like this has to do with something called proxy object that I will need to access associated object's attributes in a different way but I find it challenging to digest this concept.

At a higher level, I need to achieve showing selected recipe in detail (show) from the list (index) and showing this detail part is where the error is.

Controller

```
def index
  @recipes = Recipe.all
end

def show

end
```

View

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @recipe.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= @recipe.content %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Duration:</strong>
  <%= @recipe.duration %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Rating:</strong>
  <%= @recipe.rating %>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you sure `recipe` has a `title` attribute.  Or you are delegating it from other?

Comment: how is `@recipe` set?

Comment: Please show how do you assign `@recipe`.

Comment: updated my question. currently show is empty

Comment: There is loop for the recipe list (index.html) but do I need loop for selected recipe (show.html)?

Comment: got it solved.. I needed @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]) in show action

Answer (score 1):

@recipes = Recipe.all returns associations
you should do something like this

```
<%- @recipes.each do |recipe| %>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= recipe.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= recipe.content %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Duration:</strong>
  <%= recipe.duration %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Rating:</strong>
  <%= recipe.rating %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

It will iterate through collection and display each recipe